# React Native Loop Json Response

Tags: javascript, react-native, undefined

I have a json data like this , but I got an error , how to fix it ? my code:
I want to show the data inside the " nodes " , but first I want to check it in console.log , but I got an error

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            kasus_baru: {},
            isError : false,
            isLoading : true,
        };

    }

axios.get('xxxxxx')
    .then(res=>{
        const data_kasus = res.data;

        this.setState({kasus_baru : data_kasus });
        //console.log(this.state.kasus_baru)
        this.state.kasus_baru.nodes.map((obj,i) => {
            console.log(obj[i].kasus);
        }); 
    })
```

here's the responses :

```
{
"data": {
    "nodes": [{
            "id": 1,
            "kasus": 1,
            "klaster": "DKI JAKARTA",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "kasus": 2,
            "klaster": "DKI JAKARTA",
        }
    ]
}
```

}

why I got this error ?

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating '_this2.state.kasus_baru.nodes.map')]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because the object you are trying to map on is undefined.

> this.state.***kasus_baru***.nodes.map((obj,i) => {
>               console.log(obj[i].kasus);
>           });

I would highly suggest you debug your code and see that your JSON response is valid and that when accessing properties of objects, you verify they exist.

Meaning, check that `.nodes` is an actual property of kasus_baru.

You can do this with

`kasus_baru.hasOwnProperty("nodes")`

Also, if you have the object from your response, why access it through state?

***UPDATE (Due to OP's comment)***

The problem you have is not the loop, iterating over the nodes, but rather seeing that the data you receive from your request is valid.

In order to do that, I would do the following:

```
axios.get('xxxxxx')
.then(res=>{
    const data_kasus = res.data;
    if (data_kasus.hasOwnProperty('nodes')) {
      var nodes = data_kasus['nodes'];
      for(let index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) {
           var node = nodes[index];
           //Do your logic here...
      } //end for
    } // end if
})
```

Comment: how to loop that data inside " nodes " sir ?

Comment: @KaretNasiPadang - I updated my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Show me the code where you are trying to access the objects. As this response says you are trying to access an object whose key does not exist in the current object. For example, you are trying to access key like

data.nodes.id which will throw an exception. you need to access it data.nodes[index].id

Comment: check the length of the nodes if greater than 0 then iterate and create components in react

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem,
the answer is I must add .data after got the response

```
.then(res=>{
        const data_kasus = res.data.data;
})
```

response data :

```
{
"data": {
    "nodes": [{
            "id": 1,
            "kasus": 1,
            "klaster": "DKI JAKARTA",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "kasus": 2,
            "klaster": "DKI JAKARTA",
        }
    ]
}
```

because the json response had data key.

thank you for all of you who helping me